# Moving on from Pathfinder 2e Beginner Box

Tags: pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-beginner-box

I am currently DMing for a group of friends (first time doing pen and paper for all of us) using Roll20 and the Pathfinder **2e** Beginner Box (Menace under Otari). We like the game very much and would like to continue using the characters and dive into a deeper story/longer campaign but I am quite unsure on how to proceed.

We are level 3 as of now after the box and an adventure I wrote myself using the guidelines provided, but it took me quite a bit of time to come up with the dungeon, the characters, the loot, the balancing, ... so I would much rather use a prewritten adventure that I can GM (which is super fun!) so we can do regular sessions without me spending huge amounts of time writing the adventures on top of DMing them.

Are there any suggestions on how we can proceed to the full game (as far as I know the characters can transition easily, there's just more rules and variety in the full game of course!) with an adventure path that can be started from level 3? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to the hobby and the website! Unfortunately, we don't do game recommendations here because I may recommend XYZ while another would say ABC is better for new players, and a third person would chime in that you *have* to play *this other* adventure because its the best thing made by Paizo. (Un?)fortunately, there are not a ton of Pathfinder 2e adventures out yet. You may find the information on this [Gamemastery page](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=921) helpful, as Paizo publishes everything from one-shots to campaigns that take a year or more.

Comment: Some good places to ask for recommendations are outlined in our [Meta about forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), including [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder2e/comments/c93z2w/will_paizo_release_any_beginner_oneshots_with_2e/), as well as this [Pathfinder Discord server](https://discord.gg/pathfinder).

Comment: In the meantime, we are a great resource if you run into any non-recommendation questions or situations you don't know how to deal with. Check out our 1-page [Tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) for more info.